# PowerMock & JavaAssist "Failed to transform class"

Tags: java, javafx, junit, powermock

I have a problem with some specific classes and their transformation when used in unit tests with PowerMock.

I have looked at many SO responses already, and tried many combinations of PowerMock, JUnit, JavaAssist (overriding dependencies) but can't find a combination that works for this class.

(Some combinations of PowerMock, Junit and Javaassist didn't have this issue but the invalid stack frame one.....so stuck there also - but I would have to tackle that in a separate SO question).

If I include the class ToplevelPanel in the @PrepareForTest() list then it fails. Other JavaFX classes (like Pane.class) cause no problem.

ToplevelPanel has nothing particularly strange about it:

```
public class ToplevelPane extends Region implements BlockContainer, Bundleable {
```

Bundleable has no @Serializable annotations or anything special.

This fails when I am testing ToplevelPanel and want it in @PrepareForTest to be able to catch new()'s via whenNew() and when I am testing other classes and want to mock it.

If anyone can share a pom.xml or version combination that allows me to @PrepareForTest such a class, including capturing whenNew() it would be much appreciated.

At the bottom of this post you can find the stack trace of the failure.

## pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <powermock.version>1.5.1</powermock.version>
  </properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

## Unit Test Code

```
import nl.utwente.viskell.haskell.env.Environment;
import nl.utwente.viskell.haskell.type.Type;
import nl.utwente.viskell.ui.ToplevelPane;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Type.class, ToplevelPane.class, Environment.class})
public class ValueBlockTest {
    private ToplevelPane mockToplevelPane;

    @Before
    public void Setup() {
        mockToplevelPane = mock(ToplevelPane.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        Environment mockEnv = mock(Environment.class);
        Type mockType = mock(Type.class);
        when(mockEnv.buildType(any())).thenReturn(mockType);
        when(mockToplevelPane.getEnvInstance()).thenReturn(mockEnv);
    }

    @Test
    public void outputTest() throws Exception {
        ConstantBlock block = new ConstantBlock(mockToplevelPane, Type.con("Float"), "0.0", true);
        block.setValue("6");
        assertEquals(block.getValue(), "6");
    }
}
```

## Failure Stacktrace

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name
>   nl.utwente.viskell.ui.ToplevelPane. Reason:
>   javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to
>   javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo  at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:219)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:147)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
>     at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)    at
>   java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)    at
>   org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:143)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to
>   javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo  at
>   javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.getMethodrefType(ConstPool.java:452)     at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doInvokeMethod(Tracer.java:800)    at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode148_201(Tracer.java:597)
>     at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode(Tracer.java:81)  at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:187)  at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)  at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:164)  at
>   javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)  at
>   javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:423)    at
>   javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:405)
>     at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:768)   at
>   javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)    at
>   org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(MainMockTransformer.java:206)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(MainMockTransformer.java:142)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:65)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:215)
>     ... 56 more

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this issue cannot be resolved now in case if you really need to prepare for test the `ToplevelPane` class. But I'm not sure that it's needed. 
I noticed that the `ToplevelPane` class doesn't have static or final method. And if remove `ToplevelPane` from annotation then the test fail with another error.

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   nl.utwente.viskell.ui.ComponentLoader.loadFXML(ComponentLoader.java:25)
>     at
>   nl.utwente.viskell.ui.components.ValueBlock.(ValueBlock.java:48)
>     at
>   nl.utwente.viskell.ui.components.ConstantBlock.(ConstantBlock.java:25)
>     at ValueBlockTest.outputTest(ValueBlockTest.java:33)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)  at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
>     at javafx.scene.control.Control.(Control.java:87)   ... 51
>   more

If update Javassist to latest version, then CgLib creates strange proxy class for modified with Javassist code, so JVM throws `java.lang.VerifyError`. Mockito 1 and PowerMock uses cglib 2 which isn't supported anymore.

Mockito has been migrated to ByteButty since version 2, but it only beta. PowerMock also will be move to ByteButty, but I doubt that it will be early than the end of June.

I'll try to tackle this issue in next PowerMock release (1.6.5), but I'm not sure is it feasible.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/654) in our bug tracker. By the way, I can reproduce  the issue in case if the `javafx.scene.layout.Region` is mocked.

Comment: Thanks very much for response Arthur. I indeed ran into the VerifyErrors when using other versions.

That can be avoiding passing --noverify to the JVM when executing tests, but I didn't want to go that route on this project... Anyway I can star/follow a project or issue get updates to this specific one?

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/654) in our bug tracker. By the way, I found out there is no reason to prepare for test the `ToplevelPane` . As I see in source that the `ToplevelPane` class doesn't have static or final method. And if remove `ToplevelPane` from annotation then the test fail with another error. Also I can reproduce  the issue in case if the `javafx.scene.layout.Region` is mocked.

Comment: Thanks for the issue, will track it. I believe I need to prepare ToplevelPane for test if I want to "catch" new() calls to other mocked classes from it with whenNew() (I have read that elsewhere). Some FX classes are OK, others fail - no idea why...